# LyX says apalike isn't compatible with author-year?

Tags: lyx, natbib, apa-style

I am pretty new to LyX, and have no expirience with LaTeX. I'm writing my master's thesis in LyX, though, and I'm supposed to turn it in in a week. I want my bibliography to be "apa-ish", and have set the bibliography style to apalike.

The problem is, when i try to export my document to pdf format, I get an error message saying 
`Package natbib Error: Bibliography not compatible with author-year citations.`

What's wrong?

I'm using Jabref to organice my references, by the way, but i doubt that has got anything to do with it.

Edit: I should probably add that I do not face any such problems when using author-year citations with the plainnat bibliography style.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You may have a look on [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436).

Comment: @Jubobs Thanks! Did I do something wrong here?

Comment: No; nothing to worry about :) That was simply a warm welcome to TeX.SE, and a link to help you familiarise yourself with how the site works.

Comment: Try changing the settings under Document > Settings > Bibliography. If that doesn't work, post a minimal example.

Comment: @scottkosty I need to have author-year citations, and natbib author-year is, as far as I can see, the only option that allows for that. But I can change the settings and then change them back, if that might work somehow?

Comment: Have you tried using the [`apacite` package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/apacite)?

Comment: @Andrew Swann I think so. I think I have tried all the apa-ish options that appears on the list of styles in the bibliography settings (the ones that I get to by right-clicking on the "Bibliography" entry in the table of contents). Perhaps I should have done something some other place, to be able to use the package?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems the solution this time was to simply remove the bibliography from my table of contents, then save and close LyX, then open the document again and reinsert the bibliography, before saving, closing and opening the document once more. I have no idea why it worked, though.